# <a> with :hover or <div> with hover event for buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm usually using an `<a>` to make block type buttons for example:

```
a
{
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}

a:hover
{
    background-color:#c80000;
}
```

Then I put `href="javascript:void(0);"` on the `<a>` tag. I'm doing this because `:hover` on a `div` element is not good for backwards compatibility. This being said I was thinking originally to use as little JavaScript as possible but I'm starting to think doing this approach is not a great thing?

What would you guys use?

**EDIT:**
I only bring this up because I noticed that Google+ was using  for some of their buttons.

**EDIT #2:**
I also noticed on Google+ they have a slight animation on their buttons, so maybe that's why they are using 's

Comment: The psuedo-class `:hover` works in all browsers, even IE6. If you're looking for `:hover` (and :active, :focus, etc) support for non-anchor elements in IE6: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

div:hover will work on all browsers except Internet Explorer 6. But that browser is more than 10 years old.

The only downside of using div:hover in IE6 is that they won't get the hover effect, but they can still use (click) the button. So it won't break in IE6, just look a little bit different than in other browsers.

Comment: I ended up going with this. Originally I wanted to used the $.hover function to animate between 2 css classes but I guess I need jQueryUI for that.

Comment: You could use css transitions. But they are only supported in IE10. The do however work in all other browsers, so people using these browsers get a nicer experience.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do `<a href='#' onclick='return false;'>`.  (Thanks commenters!)

You shouldn't feel constrained to use 'as little javascript as possible', but also I don't think javascript is necessary for this particular bit.

EDIT: in case I didn't answer your question directly, I don't think there's anything wrong with using `<a>`, `<input>`, or `<button>`, but I'd stay away from `<div>` if possible if only because it is not as semantically specific.

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="return false;">...</a>

Comment: Right, just using href='#' would make the page jump to top after the click. Said by another Dave...

Answer (score 1):

Use the div + jQuery IMO

```
$('.myDivClass').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','#c80000');
    }, function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
});
```

Comment: Why use javascript when css will suffice?  Does this make it work in browsers <= IE6?

Comment: Why have an unused Anchor tag that's a block?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a div.  Unless you need to go back to, say, IE 5-6 then it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever html element is semantically correct.  If you are making buttons, why not use `<button>`?

Answer (score 0):

I use `<a>`'s quite often for this, actually. Every browser works with them, and it's usually just easier that way. Why use a div when you don't need to?

Comment: But you still need to return false onclick so isn't that javascript?

Comment: Ryan, well no, your don't have to. Nevertheless, I realized I was fundamentally wrong so I removed it. void(0) is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Using anchor gives your user ability to right-click on it and open link in another tab. Also if you want for search engines to follow links I'd leave 'a'.
I usually use 'div' in case where it is dynamic behavior meaning its not simple redirect to different URL but some AJAX or DOM altering action.